Is there a way to operate a battery operated device other than SPST or SPDT switches?
I'm building a small, handheld, battery operated, audio device, where space is a premium. Currently the device is operated by a 9v battery that is fed into an LM7805 voltage regulator, which drives the load.  My 9v battery pack does have an on/off switch (SPST), but if I forget to turn it off, well, the battery is drained in about a week, maybe less.
The device has two momentary type button/switches.  A play button, and a record button.  The device can hold about 15 seconds of audio.  When you press and hold the record button, you can then speak into the mic to record your message.  When you press the play button, your message is fed into an amplifier and played over a speaker.
I could use SPDT switches for the play and record buttons, but the ones I've found so far are too big and simply do not fit into the current device configuration.  The application for the SPDT switch would be to splice the 9v power through one side of the play button and the "play" functionality through the other side of the switch.  The device boots up and starts to play fast enough that the boot delay is not noticeable.  The record button would then be spliced in a similar fashion.
So I started thinking and looking for power transistors and found one that is 2A in a small SMD package, and some small 100ma transistors as well.  So, I came up with the following diagram to simulate the SPDT switches, and the simulator seems to work OK, but I'm just a novice electrical engineer and a few things about this circuit seem wrong, but I cannot put my finger on the basic problem, assuming there is a problem.
Could anyone confirm if this circuit is viable, or point out what is wrong with it, as in why it wouldn't work, or if it would damage parts of the circuit or the load itself?  More notes are listed below the image.  Other approaches to solving this problem are welcome as well.
For the active simulation, Click Here.


Q1-Q4 are all PNP transistors
Q1-Q2: For the datasheet, click here
Q3-Q4: For the datasheet, click here
The simulator works best on a pc, however, if your using a tablet or phone, simply hold the switch down for a few seconds and then tap "Edit", and then un-check the "momentary switch" checkbox and then tap "OK" to save your changes.  You can then simply tap the switch to turn it on or off.


You need to throw away the prehistorical LM7805 that has huge quiescent current of 3mA typical, and get something much more modern, say, from Analog Devices or Texas Instruments, with shutdown current well under 1uA.

Why is your 7805 used as an adjustable voltage regulator so incorrectly? You don't need to use two transistors at its input.

@Andyaka is correct.  The simulator does not have a 7805, but it does have a LM317, so I just added the resistors to play with the circuit in the simulator, my physical device is currently using the 7805 voltage regulator.  Sorry for the confusion.

@Ale..chenski I'm not sure a "modern" voltage regulator would work because, at least part of the load does not ever shutdown.  At any rate, if you have something specific in mind, I'd like to take a look at it.

Your load is always on, but you are complaining that your battery drains out in a week or less if you forget to disconnect it. This doesn't compute. I am saying that ~3mA parasitic drain of 7805 takes ~400-500 mAh alone from your battery. In general, "9V" and  "LM7805" doesn't bode well for a "small battery-operated device" where a "space is at premium".  I am just trying to help. To start, you should not use linear voltage regulator for 9 to 5 conversion.
